# How to plot a spherically symmetric function for radius

Tags: plotting

I have some spherically symmetric functions of radius r. (Charge densities of the proton and neutron.) How can I 3D plot them in Mathematica? Od course, I know how to plot them in 2D versus r.

Comment: may be [SphericalPlot3D](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SphericalPlot3D.html)

Comment: Plz show your function and equations at least!

Comment: Thanks. That is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

A simple SphericalPlot3D or DensityPlot3D would only show you a sphere. To get a more telling plot, use "SliceDensityPlot" Like e.g.:

```
fun[r_] = Exp[-(r - 1)^2];
SliceDensityPlot3D[
 fun[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]
```

[image]